# Best way to loop through a dictionary embedded in list and assign key values to variables

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

High Level: I am trying to assign identical keys with unique values to their own respective variables. The number of identical keys can be 1 or many. I have a list that is shown here:
`[{'client_id_new': 'client key 1'}, {'client_id_new': 'client key 2'}]`

This line allows me to retrieve the number of identical keys: `newClientIds = sum('client_id_new' in d for d in parsed)`
I subtract 1 from this value so it can be in line with an index beginning at 0.

My question: What is the best way to assign the unique values to variables that will iterate throughout the entirety of the dictionary?

Adding to question:
I would like to access the dictionary values in the list and assign them to a variable that contains the entirety of values from the list separated by commas.

So for example, a for loop that spits out an end result looking like this:
`print(allValues)`
All values(a string variable would look something like this):
`"client key 1", "client key 2"`

If there was more values up above like:

```
[{'client_id_new': 'client key 1'}, {'client_id_new': 'client key 2'}, {'client_id_new': 'client key 344'}, {'client_id_new': 'client key 327'}]
```

Then the output of the 'allValues' variable would look like this:

`"client key 1", "client key 2", "client key 344", "client key 327"`

my attempt looks something like this but im not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
count = 0

while (count <= newClientIds):
    newString = parsed[count] + newString
    count += 1
    print(newString)
```

Comment: your demonstration was excellent, your question wasn’t clear, can you explain what is your input, what the expected output?

Comment: Thank you! Sure, my question and ultimately what I want a loop to do or best way of doing this is to run through the embedded dictionary in the list and assign the identical keys to their own unique variable.

Comment: can you change your question and add example input and output? like this : `myinput = [...]` etc.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (count <= newClientIds):
    if (count == 0):
        newString = parsed[count]['client_id_new']
    else:
        newString = parsed[count]['client_id_new'] + ", " + newString
            
    count += 1
```